# Is any other religion or civilization mentioned in Mahabharata, Ramayana or other Hindu holy books?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, history, other-religions

Recently, I had a discussion with my friend regarding which civilization of the world is the most ancient. We've been through some Wiki links according to which more or less Sindhu Civilization is one of the most or (one and only) ancient civilization.

**I would like to know are there any chapters, *shlokas* or poetry which mention any religion or civilization other than Hinduism?**

I can see Ravana is not from India, he is from Sri Lanka and he was a devotee of Lord Shiva which in turn they call it as Hindu.

Can someone explain with links or trusted facts that if any Hindu related books like Upanishads, Bhagavad Gita, etc mention any other religion or civilization?

Why we had this doubt is because Lord Rama was rich and powerful king of that time. Why did he ever try to invade or explore other places in the world ? Also in Mahabharata, Kauravas always want Pandavas part?

Or is it that in those times no other kingdom existed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.. Are you inquiring about other civilizations mentioned in Malabharata/Ramayana/other Hindu epics? If yes, then the answer is affirmative. There are description of kingdoms as far as Greece (Yavana) mentioned in Mahabharata. 
BTW, Ravana wasn't from Srilanka. He migrated to Srilanka.

Comment: At the time that the Vedas were first exposed to man, there wasn't much of any civilization (except maybe the Egyptians) or any noteworthy religions around to talk about. Where to invade? Most of the world was small agricultural settlements...

Comment: @VineetMenon Yes My question is are there any civilizations or religions mentioned in Hindu epics ? Greece mentioned in Mahabaratha could you elobrate that please

Comment: @Babel, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yavana_Kingdom#References_in_Mahabharata and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yona

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, Sumerian and Egyptian civilizations were prominent during IVC who know among each other and traded among each other. In South Amer. Incas and Aztecs were powerful, though.

Comment: @VineetMenon Incas were thousands of years later. Aztecs were just starting about 2000 BC. Forgot about the Sumerians; but judging by the Epic of Gilgamesh they were not advanced philosophically, and neither were the Egyptians. Came across an interesting book which I will be reading next month - "The Roots of Hinduism: The Early Aryans and The Indus Civilization" by Asko Parola published this year.

Comment: Aztecs:Yes. Not as old as IVC, but considerable nonetheless. Sumerian: not being advanced philosophically. IDK, it could be subjective. Hindu philosophy matured only recently with Upanishads.

Comment: as far as i see...before we discuss about other religions in our scriptures...has any scripture spoke about hindu religion? i guess religions were not there at that time...there would be only "way of living" or civilizations. infact name hindu itself cannot be attributed to a religion, as i believe hindu is used to refer to the people who lived on the other side of the sindhu river.

Comment: Until the man attained intelligence and selfishness religion was not born. All the works like vedas or any other should be treated universal and scientific. we should bond them with any religion...like invention of electricity or steam engine.

Answer (score 6):

The Atharva Veda itself has mantras which clearly mention that earth will have people who will speak different languages and who will be following different religions ( Dharma ) depending on the different places of their abode.

> Janam Vibhrati VahudhA VichAsam - 1
>
> **NAnAdhArmAn Prithvi - 2**
>
> YathA Okasam - 3
>
> Sahasram DhArA Dravinasya Me DuhAm - 4
>
> Dhruveva Dhenuh Anapasphuranthi - 5

### Meaning

> Earth has people who speak various tongues - 1,
>
> **and those who have various religions - 2,**
>
> according to their places of abode - 3,
>
> (May She) pour for me treausres in a thousand streams - 4,
>
> like a constant cow that never fails - 5.
>
> **Atharva Veda, Kanda 12, Sukta 1, Mantra 45.**

Answer (score 3):

In the Srimad Bhagavatam (Bhagavata Purana) verse 2.4.18 and also in the purport a detailed description of several civilizations is given (please read synonyms and purport at the link below):
http://vedabase.com/sb/2/4/18/en

> "Kirāta, Hūṇa, Āndhra, Pulinda, Pulkaśa, Ābhīra, Śumbha, Yavana,
>   members of the Khasa races and even others addicted to sinful acts can
>   be purified by taking shelter of the devotees of the Lord, due to His
>   being the supreme power. I beg to offer my respectful obeisances unto
>   Him."

And as far as other religions is concerned, a religion established by Buddha is mentioned in the Bhagavatam 2.7.37:
http://vedabase.com/sb/2/7/37/en

> "When the atheists, after being well versed in the Vedic scientific
>   knowledge, annihilate inhabitants of different planets, flying unseen
>   in the sky on well-built rockets prepared by the great scientist Maya,
>   the Lord will bewilder their minds by dressing Himself attractively as
>   Buddha and will preach on subreligious principles."

Comment: Do you think all these ` Kirāta, Hūṇa, Āndhra, Pulinda, Pulkaśa, Ābhīra, Śumbha` are different civiliazations .. As I can see Andra, Kirata, Huna,..etc are part of India So I can see they are belonge to Hindhu.. They are not different Only `Yavana` is from west according to my knoweldge correct me if I am wrong !!

Comment: @Babel Did you read all in there at the link? If you're not then first do it ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  white people practicing different religion are mentioned in Mahabharata. There is a passage in Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCXXXVII which has been interpreted by a Professor Weber as a description of Christian worship in the Mediterranean area probably witnessed by Hindu pilgrims.  Sri K.M. Ganguli, the translator thinks that the Mahabharata is describing people from the Roman Republic.

> 'The men that inhabit that island have complexions as white as the
>   rays of the Moon and that are devoted to Narayana. Worshippers of that
>   foremost of all Beings, they are devoted to Him with their whole
>   souls. They all enter that eternal and illustrious deity of a thousand
>   rays. They are divested of senses. They do not subsist on any kind of
>   food. Their eyes are winkless. Their bodies always emit a fragrance.
>   Indeed, the denizens of White Island believe and worship only one God.
>   .......All the inhabitants were perfectly equal in energy. There was
>   no superiority or inferiority there among them. .....'

Mahabharata also mentions China, Antioch, Rome etc.

> Likewise, he [Sahadeva] used messengers to subjugate and obtain
>   tribute from the Pandya, the Dravidas, the Chodras, the Keralas, the
>   Talavanas, the Kalingas, the Ushtrakarnikas, the **Antakhis**, the **Romas**,
>   and the city of the **Greeks**.

Mahabharata Sabha Parva Section 253(28) translated by Bibek Debroy

Antakhis and Romas have been identified by scholars as Antioch and Rome respectively.

> There were large and colourful garments pleasant to the touch from
>   **Bahlika** and **China**. …………………………… Shakas, Tukharas, Kankas, **Romashas** and
>   men with horns brought as tribute one hundred million horses that
>   could travel great and long distances.

Mahabharata Sabha Parva Section 272(47) translated by Bibek Debroy

Bahlika has been identified as Bactria and Romashas have been identified as Romans.

Answer (score 0):

According to your last line, you want to ask why Lord Ram or any other great Ancient kings of India never attacked other places?
That is because of our culture and philosophy. Our philosophy was "Live and let others live". We wanted to win other with our wisdom. That's why we were called "**[JagatGuru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagadguru)**" (Guru of the world).

**Other religion:**

For this you have to know what is "religion". Most of the people link it with "Dharma", although Dharma is a Sanskrit world which means "how to live the life". So according to our philosophy in whole world there is only one dharma, but many religions (panths or ways). In ancient times there as only sanatan way of living life. These religions (Muslims, Hindu, Christian, Jain, Buddha) came very recently (in a span of last 3000 years). So in our scriptures, you will not find any other religion name.

But in [Bhavishya Puran](https://archive.org/details/puran_bhavishya), there is a mention of Pagambar Mohammad. It says that in future there will be a person called(Mahamad), who will born in a desert place.

**Other civilizations:**

Civilization is not related with religion. Civilization is more related to geographical location. So we generally hear about civilizations mostly related to some river. because A river can provide you everything for your social and personal needs.

Comment: Moreover, according to many researches, Lord Rama used to rule over most of the Earth.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE. You need to reference to the exact quote if you cite a reference. That would be more helpful than letting readers find out for themselves.

Comment: It would me more help ful if you can give that Bhavishya Puran in english version and also please rewrite the phrase or parva which they have mentioned in that Bhavishya purana instead just giving link. Thanks

Comment: many scholars believe that 'Bhavishya Purana' is not authentic. There isn't a single manuscript of Bhavishya Purana published before British.